# How to re-assign new data to ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two ng-repeat sections in my HTML as below:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="location in global.locations | limitTo: 1 ">

    <md-select  name="location_id" ng-model="location" ng-change="getSingleLocations(location)">
        <md-option ng-repeat="location in global.locations" ng-value="location.slug">
   {{ location.location_name }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-card>
```

When I change inner repeat then outer repeat content should be change as per the selected one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you make plunker or code pen so that we can better understand problem

Comment: @VickyKumar, I am explaning:

Comment: @VickyKumar, Two ng-repeat are there... I have set limitTo : 1 for outer repeat section , so there will be only one record displayed... Now Inner repeat section (dropdown field) is polulated with all the records.... and when I change it then ng-change event is fired and outer repeat should be change as per the selected value in Inner repeat.... I hope I am clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think without a plunkr you won't get a solution. But in the code here I see a few problems, first of all, first ng-repeat uses location as the iteration item name, and second one uses exactly the same name - this is wrong, the second should use its own name. 
Second issue - the ng-model of the second ng-repeat uses again the same variable name - this will contain the selected value so it has to be a different object - I would call it selectedLocation.

Third thing which I don't really get is why you need the first ng-repeat - the nice part about angularjs is data binding, and once you have the ng-model populated by angular, you can use that one for the md-card something like this:

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-title>
      <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-headline">{{selectedLocation.slug}}</span>
      </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedLocation">
        <md-option ng-repeat="location in global.locations track by $index" value="{{location.slug}}">
   {{ location.location_name }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments... this answer is very helpful for me.